# Не сериализуются internal поля

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, сериализация

Мне нужно сохранить список **List**, который содержит экземпляры класса **Inventory**. Структура класса **Inventory**:

```
internal class Inventory
{
    // This class represents the player's inventory.

    internal int UserId { get; set; }
    
    internal Pet Pet { get; set; }
    internal Computer Computer { get; set; }
}
```

Классы **Pet**, **Computer** содержат аналогичные свойства. Для сериализации использую **Newtonsoft.Json**, вот код метода для десериализации:

```
    internal static void Write(List<Inventory> toSerialize)
    {
        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
            toSerialize,
            Formatting.Indented
        );

        FileService.WriteString(jsonText);
    }
```

Но вместо ожидаемой структуры

```
[
  {
    "UserId": 12345,
    "Pet": {
      "Health": 100,
      "MoneyMultiplier": 0.2
    },
    "Computer": {
      "SupportHealth": 100
    }
  }
]
```

Я получаю строку такого вида:

```
[
    {
    
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас свойства объявлены как internal. Измените модификатор видимости на public, либо добавьте атрибут:

```
[JsonProperty]
internal int UserId { get; set; }
```

См. например тут: [JSON Serializer object with internal properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26873755/5752652)

Я лично в последнее время не люблю эту ручную работу - поэтому предпочитаю задавать политики приложения и тому подобные вещи. В Json.Net можно настроить дефолтный резолвер, подробнее см. тут: [JSON.Net: Force serialization of all private fields and all fields in sub-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24106986/5752652)